# An error has Occurred During Report proccesing

Tags: .net, reporting-services

When I'm running the report I'm getting that message above.
The Report Works fine when I press the "Run Report" Button but I want also to avoid
that annoying message that appears when the page loads.

I've tried to set the report viewer control to Enable = false;
and only after hitting the button to Enable = true;
but it didn't work.

[alt text http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/852/34545868.png](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/852/34545868.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK , I resolved it.
The table in the Report has a property called "DataSet Name",
and I only had to set that value to my DataSet name

10X anyway

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this error has something to do with your computer which doesn't have [Microsoft Report Viewer Redistributable 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=cc96c246-61e5-4d9e-bb5f-416d75a1b9ef&displaylang=en) installed